# Как развиваться в олимпиадном программировании?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада

С недавнего времени меня очень зайтересовало олимпиадное программирование.

Я учусь на первом курсе.
Основы языка и несложные алгоритмы я уже выучил.
Но вот как мне дальше развиваться не знаю.

Что учить?
 Где учить?
Где можно поучаствовать?
 Какие-нибудь курсы?
 Какие-нибудь форумы?

---

Буду очень признателен если кто-то поможет.

Comment: Олимпиадное программирование — бесполезная фигня, отрывающая от реальности и мешающая заниматься нормальным полезным программированием. Не нужно в нём развиваться.

Comment: А чем олимпиадное программирование отличается от олимпиад по математике? Хотя есть расхождение в вопросе о необходимости таких олимпиад, думаю, многие здесь примут нужность таких олимпиад без лишних споров.

Comment: Это уход в сторону. Математические олимпиады нужны?

Comment: @mathem `А чем олимпиадное программирование отличается от олимпиад по математике?` - тем что олимпиады по математике имеют отношение к реальной математике, а олимпиадное программирование к продуктовой разработке не имеет почти никакого отношения. Аналогия с охотой на мамонта все-таки ближе к реальности.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Выскажу своё мнение, так как много лет занимался олимпиадами и был участником чемпионата мира по программированию (19-е место). Сейчас я программист-математик в довольно узкой области, но владею этой областью как профессионала международного уровня. Не смог бы стать таким профессионалом если бы вовремя не соскочил с иглы олимпиад.

Первое, что вы обязаны понимать: олимпиады - это игра. Она полезная, развивает **некоторые** полезные навыки программирования и немаловажную способность к оптимизации. Когда я закончил играть в эту игру лет 13 назад, я был удивлён тому, насколько лучше любых других программистов я умею писать быстрый и эффективный код, который они даже представить себе не могли (когда речь идёт о сложных задачах). Но главное в этой игре - ВОВРЕМЯ УЙТИ. В один прекрасный момент вы должны понять, что наступила *точка насыщения*, после которой вместо развития начинается деградация. Вы начинаете работать уже не на развития своих навыков, а на оттачивание до совершенства именно соревновательных навыков, которые на реальной работе не нужны и даже вредны.

Второе: олимпиадники не способны решать задачи, на которые нужно потратить больше 5 часов времени. Сколько я не преподавал, ни разу не попался человек, успешный в олимпиадах, но при этом способный решать сложные научные задачи. Они привыкли, что можно написать некий просто хороший код, эффективнее которого не смогут написать **почти** 100% обычных программистов, и этого достаточно. Но нет, в научных расчётах попадаются такие задачи, которые нужно пробивать месяцами упорного труда типа "написал - стёр - написал заново", этот цикл может длиться десятки итераций и приходится применять те приёмы, которые НЕ нужны в олимпиадах. Они этого не умеют. И, что ужасно, не могут себя заставить переучиться с игры на кропотливый труд.

Третье: олимпиадники не способны писать грамотный промышленный код. Их можно этому научить, но не всегда получается. Да, их код очень хорош в плане эффективности, они чувствуют код как свою часть тела и знают как он будет работать. Многие из них даже не делают ошибок в коде - он сразу запускается и работает правильно (так было у меня лет 13 назад, код **на домашних тренировках** я писал в "блокноте" (без плюсов) и он сразу компилировался и работал без ошибок, можно даже не проверять, но этот навык не нужен и быстро теряется). Но одна беда: этот код не понятен другим людям, он не структурирован так, чтобы в нём легко можно было разобраться, чтобы заменить одну часть кода другой, его ВООБЩЕ невозможно поддерживать, можно только удалить и написать заново.

Четвёртое: из второго и третьего пунктов следует важная деталь - параллельно с олимпиадами нужно работать над реальными задачами, имеющими практический смысл. Это могут быть игры (обязательно по правилам разработки игр, а не самопал), могут быть научные расчёты (обязательно по правилам той научной лаборатории, где работаете), могут быть промышленные задачи (по ВСЕМ правилам промышленного кода и разработки программного обеспечения). Только так вы не станете развитым лишь на один бок и не будете мучиться в своей профессиональной карьере.

Пятое. Не впадайте в демонизм и не пытайтесь унижать своих собратьев, не прошедших олимпиадную школу. Они никогда не напишут какой-нибудь алгоритм Форда-Фалкерсона так, чтобы он работал быстро и правильно, у них в голове нет 70-100 алгоритмов, которые вы можете быстро напечатать за несколько минут, они даже не слышали, что такое максимальный поток, а вы знаете 15 алгоритмов его поиска наизусть. Это приводит к ощущению какой-то возвышенности и важности. На самом деле вы должны понимать главное: в реальной жизни вы - бесполезный мусор, если не умеете решать реальные задачи. Держите этот момент в голове, если захотите кого-то унизить, кто не знает что такое динамическое программирование, например.

Шестое. Развитие вас как олимпиадника должно быть постоянным, нельзя останавливаться. Обязательно посещайте сборы программистов-олимпиадников, таких сейчас много, и когда нет сборов, каждый день решайте задачи с разных серверов. В наше время были популярными acm.timus.ru и acm.sgu.ru, сейчас я даже не знают, работают ли они, но сейчас полно других вариантов: topcoder, codeforces (загуглите). Без сборов ваше обучения будет очень слабым. Без каждодневных тренировок на серверах (пусть хоть полчасика в день) - тоже.

Седьмое. Как только поймёте, что дошли до точки насыщения и дальнейший рост в олимпиадах приводит только к развитию навыков скорости и соревнования, а классические основы всех алгоритмов вам уже известны, валите оттуда как можно скорее. Потому что с этого момента начинается ваша деградация как человека практического. Сразу переключайтесь на реальную работу, изучайте стандарты программирования, которые не смогли изучить в бытность олимпиадником и беритесь за реальные задачи. Если вы проигнорировали совет делать это параллельно, то придётся несколько лет переучиваться.

Восьмое. Игры затягивают в себя своим соревновательным духом, олимпиады насыщают гордыню и подсаживают на чувстве значимости и особенности. Помните, что это иллюзия, увод в сторону. Это хорошая школа для того чтобы научиться чувствовать код и компьютер, изучить алгоритмы, но всё остальное (призы, места, победы и поражения, взгляды юных девушек) - это туфта. Не ведитесь на неё, потом будет обидно.

Всё, желаю удачи, и да прибудет с вами здравый смысл :)

Comment: Однажды Эрнест Хемингуэй поспорил, что сможет написать самый короткий рассказ, способный растрогать любого)

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос был задан про развитие в олимпиадном программировании, а ответы про то, насколько это бесполезно и т.д... Отвечу по теме. Во-первых надо смотреть по уровню. Лично я с командой в начале тренировался на этом сайте: https://acmp.ru/. Там много простых задач, и можно потихоньку увеличивать сложность. Некоторых задач можно найти разборы на ютубе и в интернете. Так же изучайте алгоритмы! На том же сайте есть тренировки алгоритмов, и хороший сайт с алгоритмами: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/. Там есть и графы, и со строками, и на комбинаторику, и всё, что душа пожелает. А участвовать можно на соревнованиях тут: https://codeforces.com/problemset . Тут самые похожие задачи с теми, что на олимпиаде. По началу можете в архивах находить те, что с самой простой сложностью. Когда повысите уровень, можете пробывать участвовать в соревнованиях. И вообще, олимпиадное программирование мало похоже на профессиональное, но оно даст вам хорошую базу, и знание алгоритмов. И когда мы ездим на олимпиады, всегда есть возможность завести новые знакомства, и куча it компаний предлагают работу у себя. Так что это точно опыт, который не помешает. Так что не слушай некого, и занимайся тем, что нравится))

Comment: Бывает, что люди задают вопросы типа "как мне спать на потолке чтобы не падало одеяло", в этом случае глупо отвечать на вопрос прямо, следует объяснить, что на потолке лучше не спать, либо спать, но не так, чтобы оно затягивало и мешало потом жить обычной семейной жизнью (с женой, например). Вот отсюда и ответы, что олимпиады не всегда полезны, чтобы у человека не было иллюзий. И чтобы он понял: а может не тратить на это столько времени, сколько он хотел? Также рекомендую прочитать мой ответ.

Comment: Я согласен с вашим ответом, но не кажется ли вам, что еще очень рано говорить о том, когда нужно уходить? Он просто хочет попробовать, и всё. Я сам еще только на втором курсе, и занимаюсь всего 2 года, но мне хватает времени что бы практиковаться в олимпиадном программировании, читать книгу Шилда Герберта, учить C#, и изучать патерны объектно - ориентированного программирования. Так что , по-моему, всё можно совмещать, и не боятся пробовать)

Comment: Нет, не рано, если человека сильно затянет, он оттуда не вылезет без потерь для себя, поэтому лучше знать об опасности заранее. Я лишь предлагаю держать в голове эту мысль: игра - это не реальная жизнь, это лишь небольшой этап внутреннего роста и не нужно путать его с жизнью. В моей практике почти никто этого не понимал, поэтому им было трудно потом найти себя. Я рад, что вам хватает времени на другое, но лучше чтобы вы сразу параллельно пробовали себя в какой-нибудь реальной фирме, и чтобы это не мешало учёбе. Ещё можно найти руководителя по какой-нибудь хорошей научной задаче, где нужен код.

Answer (score 2):

Спортивная олимпиада поможет стать спортсменом. Математическая олимпиада поможет стать математиком. Олимпиадное программирование - не поможет стать программистом. Хобби - да. Как заменитель книг/игр - да. Как зарядка для ума - да. Как обучение программированию - нет. Слишком разные подходы к коду. Слишком разные цели у олимпиады и production.

Поэтому, если хотите развиваться, советую участвовать в открытых проектах на github, gitlab, bitbucket, sourceforge и так далее. Таким образом вы и сообществу поможете, и получите опыт работы в команде, и получите опыт участия в реальных проектах. Да к тому же будет что показать работодателю если попросят примеры кода.

Answer (score 2):

**Имхо**

Если Вы пишиете, и хотите продолжать писать на плюсах, то лучшее, что я могу Вам посоветовать,

и что максимально поспособствует Вашему развитию (сугубо мое мнение), это написание игр.


Начиная с легких консольных игр в которых будет присутствовать какая-то игровая логика,

 и двигаясь в сторону того, чтобы начинать изучать графические библиотеки, которые смогут помочь

 Вам постепенно лучше понять, как можно работать не только с консольными приложениями 

под винду, линукс и пр., а и приложения, на которые лично Вам станет приятнее смотреть.

Как вариант, начните со змейки, крестиков ноликов, тенис и т.д. 

Лично я начинал с [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/), но вариантов также достаточно много, гугл поможет выбрать Ваш.

В процессе, вероятнее всего, станет интереснее как написать более правильно, то что Вы делаете

и тогда можно будет копнуть глубже в паттерны. Книг много и каждому больше подходит свое. 

Вместе с этим можно поднатаскать и навыки алгоритмов, но не стоит пытаться выучить каждый,

 т.к. профита от этого мало и большая часть либо выучится на практике, пока Вы будете искать хорошее решение своей проблемы, либо же вовсе Вам не понадобится, в силу того, что использовать приходится в большинстве случаев именно готовые решения.


Главное - не стоит сильно закапываться в эти темы без практики, т.к. сырая теория в программировании дает невероятно маленький выхлоп, при этом без практики забывается все это очень быстро.


**Курсы**

Выбор на рынке крайне большой, но в целом, можете посмотреть бесплатные лекции на той же [Курсере](https://ru.coursera.org/specializations/c-plus-plus-modern-development) курс от Яндекса, есть чему научится.

Полезным и интересным мне показался курс про многопоточность/сокеты на [Степике](https://stepik.org/course/149/promo), опять таки бесплатный и с достаточном хорошим уровнем задач где-то после `20-30%` курса.

**Полезно**

Если Вы в универе на 1 курсе, то навык, который в какой-то степени уже можно начать развивать, и который будет крайне полезен для Вас, как для программиста всегда - чтение чужого кода.

Элементарно можете начать с помощи одногруппникам с его лабой, которая почему-то не работает. Пытаясь понять его код (если он не будет у всех копипастой) Вы будете понемногу, но учится работать с чужим кодом. Т.к. в этой професии работать с чужим кодом зачастую приходится *ооочень* часто, то такой навык будет очень сильно упрощать Вашу первую и последущие.

А еще, никогда не ленитесь дебажить, если что-то не работает, и сразу непонятно, что именно сломалось, в первую очередь попытайтесь изучить (если еще не изучили), а после применить свои скиллы дебагинга и найти корень зла в Вашей программе.

П.С.

Слегка сумбурно, скорее всего еще подкорректирую и дополню, но в целом, желаю успеха в Ваших начинаниях.

Answer (score 1):

Мой любимий сайт с задачами по программированию, очень хорошо можно прокачать свой уровень и главное увидеть прогресс.

Решая регулярно эти задачи можно подготовится к олимпиаде и не только, очень многое вам пригодится в учебе и в будущей работе.

https://www.codewars.com/

Еще классний момент, сайт исходя из вашей инфы найдет других пользователей, которые учаться с вами в одном универе. Можно найти новых друзей.

Удачи!

Comment: не советую этот сайт для олимпиадника. Задачи почти все решаются стандартными методами и крайне простые.